# Selenium webdriver wait until not working

Tags: java, selenium, htmlunit-driver

Hi I am trying to wait until an element is loaded in selenium. This code I have copied from the Selenium website tutorial. But there is an error in the last line.

Error is "`Cannot resolve method 'until(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition<org.openqa.selenium.Alert>)`"

```
HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
driver.get(url);
WebDriverWait myWait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
myWait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
```

Can somebody help

Comment: Are you maybe using an older version of Selenium which doesn't support 'until'?

Comment: I am using 2.44.0 . Isn't that the latest?

Comment: It is... It is also on your Classpath?

Comment: Its showing like a compiler error

Comment: Then its not on your classpath.

Comment: Why you are using HtmlUnitDriver? Have you tried with webdriver and browser?

Comment: Are u using htmlunitdriver in same version as selenium??